# Where I doing mistake using laravel when I show a image

Tags: html, css, laravel-6

I don't  understand where I doing the mistake. Why the information don't show in the view page. 
I get this error :

```
Trying to get property 'patient_image' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\HealthCare\resources\views\backEnd\appointment\viewAppointment.blade.php)
```

My Controller :

```
public function appointmentView($id)
{   
        $appDetails = DB::table('appointments')
        ->where('appointments.patient_id',$id)
        ->join('patients', 'appointments.patient_id', '=', 'patients.patient_userID')
        ->select('appointments.*','patients.*')
        ->get()
        ->first();

        $doctorsLists = Doctor::groupBy('doctor_specialty')->get()->all();          
        $specialityLists = Specialist::get()->all();
    return view('backEnd.appointment.viewAppointment',['appDetails'=>$appDetails, 'doctorsLists'=>$doctorsLists , 'specialityLists'=>$specialityLists]);
}
```

Router.php

```
Route::get('/admin/appointment/view/{id}', 'AppointmentController@appointmentView');
```

View page :

```
 <div class="profile-info-detail">
  <img src="{{asset($appDetails-> patient_image)}}"
                                 class="img-thumbnail" alt="profile-image">
      <h4 class="m-0"> {{$appDetails->patient_name}}</h4>
      <p class="text-muted m-b-20"><i><strong>Email : </strong>{{$appDetails->patient_email}}</i></p>
      <p class="text-muted m-b-20"><i><strong>Phone : </strong> {{$appDetails->patient_phone}}</i></p>
      <p class="text-muted m-b-20"><i><strong>Diseases Type : </strong> {{$appDetails->diseases_type}}</i></p>
      <p class="text-muted m-b-20"><i><strong>Appointment Date : </strong> {{$appDetails->app_date}}</i></p>
      <p><strong>Problem Description:</strong> {{$appDetails->message}}</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Assuming the space in `$appDetails-> patient_image` is just a formatting issue here on SO, what the error says is that `$appDetails` is not an object. For that to be true, it means your Controller method is not returning `appDetails` to the view. For that to be true it means your query is not returning a result. So, that's where you start debugging.